# How is the mean of a high dimensional random variable defined?

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables

If $X$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-valued r.v., with density $g(x)$, then $\mathbb{E}(X) := \int xg(x)dx$. But what if say $X \in \mathbb{R}^{3}?$ It can still have a density $g(x)$ such that the integral of $g$ over the whole 3-dimensional space is 1. I know for a high dimensional Gaussian, as long as we have its pdf, we know the mean and variance, but what about an arbitrary distribution? Does $\int xg(x) dx$ even make sense now?

Answer (score 2):

If $X = (X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)^T$ then the mean of $X$ is defined to be
$$
    ( \mathbb{E}[X_1], \mathbb{E}[X_2], \ldots, \mathbb{E}[X_n])^T
$$
where
$$
    \mathbb{E}[X_k] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x_k \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n - 1}} g(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{k - 1}, x_{k + 1}, \ldots, x_n)dx_1 dx_2 \ldots dx_{k - 1}dx_{k + 1} \ldots dx_n \right)dx_k
$$
i.e, the mean of the marginal distribution of the $k$-th coordinate, $X_k$ (as long as the integral above makes sense)